# How to find conjugate prior for a given distribution?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, conjugate-prior

Given a distribution $\{p(X|\theta),\theta\in\Theta\}$:

- how do you show the existence/non-existence of its conjugate prior?
- what are some general ways/principles to construct/find its conjugate prior, if there is one?
- If it exists, how do you show it is unique or not?
- If not unique, which one is the most "canonical/classical" (in your definition) one among all?

Comment: If we define a family of prior distributions $P$ to be conjugate to a likelihood if the posterior also lies in $P$, then the family of all distributions is trivially conjugate to any distribution (i.e. a conjugate prior always exists). And when a simple conjugate family exists, mixtures of this family are also conjugate (i.e. it is not unique unless it's trivial).