# What is the conjugate prior distribution?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, prior

I am new to the bayesian statistics and I most frequently see the conjugate prior distribution. Can you explain it with clear example? I would be very thankful.

Comment: other related questions include https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90969/how-to-find-conjugate-prior-for-a-given-distribution  and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59363/having-a-conjugate-prior-deep-property-or-mathematical-accident

Comment: Simple illustration of beta prior conjugate to binomial likelihood [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182174/how-to-set-values-in-a-conjugate-prior/2182491#2182491).

Answer (score 9):

A conjugate prior is a probability distribution that, when multiplied by the likelihood and divided by the normalizing constant, yields a posterior probability distribution that is in the same family of distributions as the prior.

In other words, in the formula:

$$p(\theta|x) = \frac{p(x|\theta)p(\theta)}{\int{p(x|\theta)p(\theta)d\theta}}$$

The prior $p(\theta)$ is conjugate to the posterior $p(\theta | x)$ if both are in the same family of distributions.

For example, the normal distribution is conjugate to itself, because if the likelihood and prior are normal, then so is the posterior.